# laplace solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

I have solved the following problem
\begin{align*}
-\nabla^2 u=1 \quad \text{in} \quad \Omega\\
u=0 \quad \text{in} \quad \partial\Omega
\end{align*}
For $\Omega = \{(x,y) : a^2<x^2+y^2<b^2 \} $, but i would like to solve the same problem in $\Omega = \{(x,y,z) : a^2<x^2+y^2+z^2<b^2 \} $, so i would like some help, since i'm having some trouble trying to do this, one of the problem is that i used the fact that $\theta$ was constant, but i don't know if that is still happening and what happen with the other angle, so any help would be useful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, looking for a solution depending only on $r$ seems very reasonable.

Comment: I presume you wanted $\nabla^2 u$ and not $\nabla u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exploiting the spherical symmetry we can write

$$\nabla^2u=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)=-1 \tag 1$$

for $a<r<b$.  Then, solving $(1)$ for $u$ yields

$$u=-\frac16r^2+\frac Ar+B$$

Applying the boundary conditions at $r=a$ and $r=b$ reveals

$$\frac Aa+B=\frac16 a^2\\\\\frac Ab+B=\frac16 b^2$$

Solving for $A$ and $B$ we find $A=-\frac16 ab(a+b)$ and $B=\frac16(a^2+ab+b^2)$.  Putting it all together, we obtain

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{u=\frac16 (a^2+ab+b^2-r^2)-\frac{ab(a+b)}{6r}}$$

Comment: Thank you, but i have another question, are we able to still find a solution if we don't take $\theta, \varphi$ as a constants, or is it too hard, can u give me some idea on that please

Comment: The uniqueness theorem guarantees that this is the unique solution.  So, the answer is no.  If one expands $v(r,\theta,\phi)$ is spherical harmonics, after applying the boundary conditions, we would find that all of the coefficients would vanish except the ones on $r^2$ and $r^{-1}$.  -Mark